# Column and Row Space of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

From Bernard Kolman Linear Algebra I have encountered this example.
Find a basis for column space:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-2 &0 &3 &4\\
3 & 2 & 8 &1&4\\
2 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 3\\
-1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & -3
\end{bmatrix}.$$In the question he transpose it and reduced to row echelon form.
$$A^{\mathbf{T}}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&2&-1\\
-2&2&3&2\\
0&8&7&0\\
3&1&2&4\\
-4&4&3&-3\end{bmatrix}\equiv \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\frac{11}{24}\\
0&1&0&\frac{-49}{24}\\
0&0&1&\frac{7}{3}\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$and he took firt three rows and again transpose it so he said that it is baiss for column space. But why? Why we transpose it? And why we don't just reduced it to row echelon form? Because in the previous sections, we reduced the matrix and take the pivot's in order to find a basis. I just don't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, say,$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Its column space is $\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\x\end{smallmatrix}\right]\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}$, right? But the reduced row echelon form of $A$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, and the column space of *this* matrix is $\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}$, which is *not* the previous one.

But we do *not* have the same problem with rows. The row space of a matrix and the row space of its reduced row echelon form are the same.

Comment: So, for finding row space: we take transpose and reduced it and in the end we take first matrix to choose the rows. for finding column space: we take transpose again and reduced it and in the end we take second matrix to choose the columns, right?

Comment: For finding the row space, you just reduce it and consider the row space of the reduced maatrix. No transposition is needed.

Comment: One last question, is it important to choose which matrix will we take the row and column vector? Reduced one or first one?

Comment: The reduced one, since then you know that you may ignore the rows that consist of zeros only. And furthermore the remaining rows will be linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you so much, clarificiation of your words are very good! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.